# Not receiving data in header in google calendar webhook/push_notification request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-calendar-api

I created a new channel using below code for google calendar watch events but not getting any data in header when receiving webhook from google.

```
client = Google::APIClient.new

client.authorization.access_token = "#{access_token}"

service = client.discovered_api('calendar', 'v3')

data = client.execute api_method: service.events.watch, parameters: {
  calendarId: "primary",
}, body_object: {
  id: "34234234-89ab-cdef-0123456789ab",
  type: "web_hook",
  address: "#{my_domain}/notifications"
}
```